# MySQL master-slave replication over an unstable internet link

Tags: mysql, replication

Connection from our main office to couple remote sites are pretty unstable, if I want to do a slave replication to those remote sites, I might need to increase multiple timeout values, anything else I need to aware? Also, does replication are atomic? what if connection breaks in the middle of getting data? does everything will retransfer from master to slave or slave is unaware of broken pieces?

Answer (score 2):

- Increase some of these:  `net_retry_count`, `slave_transaction_retries`, `slave_net_timeout`.
- Monitor the slaves to catch them in the case of a really long network break.  Then do `SLAVE STOP; SLAVE START;`
- Make sure `expire_logs_days` is long enough so that you won't lose binlogs.  There is no "too big", except that you could eventually run out of disk space.

Everything *should* work find after the Slave gets going again.  (There will be a delay as it "catches up".)

Comment: Thanks, how about the atomic transaction part?

Comment: If you assume the 2 do not crash, replication control will take care of that (check the options to enable transactional replication control, but everthing should be handled automatically for you -no duplicated or lost transactions. If you assume either the master or the replica can crash, then it gets a little more complicated: https://jfg-mysql.blogspot.com/2018/10/consequences-sync-binlog-neq-1-part-1.html https://jfg-mysql.blogspot.com/2018/11/master-replication-crash-safety-part-2-lagging-slaves.html